# "useFormik" cannot be called at the top level

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

Error: React Hook "useFormik" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

[image]

i cut this line from line 75 to 92  and paste in line 5 but same error (HOW TO SOLVE THIS)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Answer (score 1):

In the picture, I see you have used the `useFormik` hook outside the function component. But you have to use this inside a **React Function Component**

```js
 // import required modules & libraries
 import React from 'react';
 import { useFormik } from 'formik';
 
// A react function component
 const SignupForm = () => {
   // here it is inside the `SignupForm` component
   // useFormik Hook Start
   const formik = useFormik({
     initialValues: {
       firstName: '',
       lastName: '',
       email: '',
     },
     onSubmit: values => {
       alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
     },
   });
   // useFormik Hook End

   // Rnder the form
   return (
     <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
       <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
       <input
         id="firstName"
         name="firstName"
         type="text"
         onChange={formik.handleChange}
         value={formik.values.firstName}
       />
       <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
       <input
         id="lastName"
         name="lastName"
         type="text"
         onChange={formik.handleChange}
         value={formik.values.lastName}
       />
       <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
       <input
         id="email"
         name="email"
         type="email"
         onChange={formik.handleChange}
         value={formik.values.email}
       />
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
   );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
 const MyForm = (handleSubmit, setValues, ...) => { 
    // the hook needs to be used like this 
   const formik = useFormik({
     initialValues: {
     NameOftheUPSIProject: '',
     InformationSharedBy: '',
     InsiderTypes: '',
     ..
    },
   onSubmit: values => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
   },
  });
}
```

As seen in the above code, you can use the `useFormik` hook either inside a React `functional` component or a React `hook` function.

Reference doc: [useFormik](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik)